# How to call parent class' method from a subclass in JavaScript so that parent's local variables would be accessible?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, superclass

I'm using one of the approaches to class inheritance in JavaScript (as used in the code I'm modifying), but do not understand how to attach additional functionality for a method in a subclass to the functionality the respective parent class method already has; in other words, I want to override a parent's method in the child class with a method that besides its own sub-class-specific stuff does also the same the parent's method is doing. So, I'm trying to call the parent's method from the child's method, but is it even possible?

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7zMnW/. Please, open the development console to see the output.

Code also here:

```
function MakeAsSubclass (parent, child)
{
    child.prototype = new parent;   // No constructor arguments possible at this point.
    child.prototype.baseClass = parent.prototype.constructor;
    child.prototype.constructor = child;

    child.prototype.parent = child.prototype; // For the 2nd way of calling MethodB.
}

function Parent (inVar)
{
    var parentVar = inVar;

    this.MethodA = function () {console.log("Parent's MethodA sees parent's local variable:", parentVar);};
    this.MethodB = function () {console.log("Parent's MethodB doesn't see parent's local variable:", parentVar);};
}

function Child (inVar)
{
    Child.prototype.baseClass.apply(this, arguments);

    this.MethodB = function ()
    {
        console.log("Child's method start");
        Child.prototype.MethodB.apply(this, arguments); // 1st way
        this.parent.MethodB.apply(this, arguments); // 2 2nd way
        console.log("Child's method end");
    };
}

MakeAsSubclass(Parent, Child);

var child = new Child(7);
child.MethodA();
child.MethodB();
```

Comment: no you can't see the parents local variables.  You inherit the parents prototype chain, not their local state.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't see the parents local variables.  You inherit the parents prototype chain, not their local state.  In your case you're applying the parent function onto the child object which does not hold the state.

```
apply(this,...)
```

means that you're binding the function to the current value of this.  when you call method b from the child object, its then bound to the child, and therefore is not operating within the closure that contains the parents value.

Comment: But Parent's MethodA (called from the child object) does see the variable. I guess it's because it was recreated for the child in its constructor. However, MethodB does not.

Comment: You're calling A on a parent object.  You're calling B on a child object.  If you call A with apply(this) it will fail as well

Comment: OK, seems very odd to me. :) I mean, I do `child.MethodA();`, but it turns out I'm actually calling MethodA on a parent object!

Answer (score 2):

I would advice agains using private instance value properties like this because it messes up the prototype. Functions that need to access the private instance variable (each instance has it's own private value) can't be put on the prototype so you can't realy use it.

Here is how your code could work (but I would not do it myself):

```
var Parent = function(){
  var private=22;
  this.showPrivate=function(){
    console.log(private);
  }
}
var Child=function(){Parent.call(this)};
// the following is only usefull if you have functions
// on the parent prototype that don't use privates
Child.prototype=Object.create(Parent.prototype);
// Child.prototype.constructor would now point to Parent
// it's not needed most of the time but you can fix that
Child.prototype.constructor=Child;

var c = new Child();
c.showPrivate();
```

Here is how you could use "private" functions:

```
var Parent = function(name){
  //public instance variable
  this.name=name;
}
Parent.prototype=function(){
  // privates on the prototype (shared among instances)
  var privateFunction=function(me){
    console.log("private function called in:"+me.name);
    console.log("shared in "+me.name
      +" is now:"+shared+" setting it to 'changed'");
    shared="Changed";
  }
  // private shared value
  var shared="Parent"
  return{
    constructor:Parent,
    publicFn:function(){
     privateFunction(this); 
    }
  };
}();

var Child=function(name){Parent.call(this,name)};
Child.prototype=Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor=Child;

var c = new Child("child1");
var c2 = new Child("child2");
c.publicFn();
c2.publicFn();//shared is already changed by 'child1'
```

More info on constructor functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711)

Comment: Thanks for the reference on the private functions and private static/shared variables! But about the private instance values: what exactly is your example different from mine? "showPrivate" function seems a lot like my "MethodA", which can access the local variable all right. It's "MethodB" I'm having problems with.

Comment: @Janis I don't know, have no idea what your code was supposed to do. From the description of your question I tried to post code that shows how to override parent functions. The example using private instance value properties (everything in the constructor function body) I guess that isn't shown overriding because I never use that. I guess you can save the function of the parent and then call it before calling Parent.call(this) in Child's body.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `var parentVar = inVar;` is a local and private variable available only in the `Parent()` function and visible only to functions defined in the same scope (`Parent()`).

I think that best way here would be to modify the Parent class in such way that the `parentVar` wouldn't be private, but public:

```
function Parent(inVar) {

    this.parentVar = inVar;

}
```