# Javascript builder pattern using private variables

Tags: javascript, builder-pattern

I'm trying to create a builder pattern in Javascript that uses private variables, while providing one public accessor (`fullName`) that returns a mashup of all the other properties. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368580/using-object-defineproperty-and-accessing-a-variable-in-private-scope) suggests that I can use `Object.defineProperty` inside the person constructor in order to access private variables, but it doesn't work - `instance.fullName` is always `undefined`.

How can I get this working so that the builder pattern variables remain private, but the public accessor has access to them throughout the build chain?

```
var Person = function () {
    var _firstName, _lastName

    Object.defineProperty(this, "fullName", {
        get: function () {
            return _firstName + ' ' + _lastName;
        }
    });

    return {
        firstName: function (n) {
            _firstName = n
            return this
        },
        lastName: function (n) {
            _lastName = n
            return this
        }
    }
}

var x = new Person().firstName('bob').lastName('dole');

console.log(x.fullName); // always undefined
```

Comment: I suspect it's because the object being returned from `Person` is different from the `this` on which `Object.defineProperty()` is called.

Comment: Hmmmmm yeah, frankly `Object.defineProperty()` doesn't really feel like the right way to go about this anyway.

Comment: If I have to do it with public properties, that's fine, but even using `this._firstName` etc. doesn't work with this design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, change the object passed to `defineProperty()`:

```
var Person = function () {
    var _firstName, _lastName

    var _self = {
        firstName: function (n) {
            _firstName = n
            return this
        },
        lastName: function (n) {
            _lastName = n
            return this
        }
    }

    Object.defineProperty(_self, "fullName", {
        get: function () {
            return _firstName + ' ' + _lastName;
        }
    });

    return _self;
}

var x = new Person().firstName('bob').lastName('dole');

console.log(x.fullName); // bob dole
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/peztf9qs/

Comment: HOT! Thanks a bunch. Makes sense.